# What is this question about? Is it a standard form question????

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I really dont understand these questions..

$x=9 \times 10^{2m}$ where $m$ is an integer. 
Find in standard form, an expression for $\sqrt{x}$
and...
$y=9 \times 10^{2n}$ where $n$ is an integer
Find in standard form an expression for $y^{2/3}$
Give your answer as simply as possible.

Answer (score 1):

To help you better understand the questions:

Assuming $x = 9\cdot 10^{2m}, y = 9\cdot 10^{2n},$ and the second question is to express $y^{2/3}$ given $y$, then you are being asked to express

$(1)\quad \sqrt x = \sqrt{9\cdot 10^{2m}},\;$

$(2) \quad y^{2/3} = (9\cdot 10^{2n})^{2/3}= \sqrt[\large 3]{(9\cdot 10^{2n})^2}$

in standard, simplified form.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sqrt{9\times 10^{2m}} = \sqrt{9} \sqrt{(10^m)^2} = 3\times 10^m.
$$

Also, recall that $y^{2/3}$ is $\sqrt[3]{y}^2$.

Comment: Make that last $9$ a $3$, and make the exponent $m$ instead of $n$.